# Python send e-mail async with trio

Tags: python, email, asynchronous, smtp, python-trio

I want to send e-mails in an asynchronous way by using the package trio. I found the package aiosmtplib, but this is only for asyncio.

Is there any package which I can use for it, or has anyone an idea of how to implement this with trio?

Update:
I found this package [mailers](https://pypi.org/project/mailers/), which describes that it uses anyio, so that trio can be used. But under the hood, it uses aiosmtplib, too.

Comment: You can use `trio_asyncio` to call asyncio code from Trio. Doesn't work with all asyncio-using packages, but at first glance `aiosmtplib` looks like it should be OK.